# using xpath with namespace from a java class

Tags: java, xpath, namespaces

I am trying to parse an xml document with namespace using XPATH. I have read how it is supposed to be done. I have implemented NamespaceContext as well. But, I still am not getting the values. I think I am missing something simple.

My xml input is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:customer xmlns:ns1="http://test/ns1">
    <ns1:name>john</ns1:name>
</ns1:customer>
```

My Main file is TestXMLPath

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String myInputXML = "src/testxmlpath/input-with-namespace.xml";
  DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();        

  String expression ="/ns1:customer/ns1:name";

  Document document = db.parse(new File(myInputXML)) ;
  XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
  xpath.setNamespaceContext(new SimpleNamespaceContextImpl());
  String value = xpath.evaluate(expression,document);
  System.out.println("value" + value);
}
```

my NamespaceContext implementation is

```
public class SimpleNamespaceContextImpl implements NamespaceContext {

@Override
public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
    System.out.println("getNameSpace for prefix "+prefix);        
    if (prefix == null) {            
        throw new NullPointerException("Null prefix");
    } else if ("ns1".equals(prefix)) {            
        return "http://test/ns1";
    } else if ("xml".equals(prefix)) {            
        return XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI;
    } else {            
        return XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI;
    }
}

@Override
public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {        
    return "ns1";
}

@Override
public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
    return null;
}
}
```

I print out when a method gets called. Here is the output.

```
getNameSpace for prefix ns1
getNameSpace for prefix ns1
value
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I can't understand, why won't it work ??

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. Output:

```
getNameSpace for prefix ns1
getNameSpace for prefix ns1
valuejohn
```

Are you sure you're loading the right document? I'm using Xerces to build the document and Saxon to evaluate the XPath. A dump of the relevant classes:

```
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
class net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl
```

Comment: I found the problem !! 

Problem was not creating the Document from xml file as namespace aware. 

Here is the change..

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Comment: @user1309197 - Ah, yeah, that makes sense and is a good practice. It's not necessary to set it with *all* parsers, which is why it worked when I ran it, but it's a good idea to always do it.