# XPathFactoryImpl not able to identify the root node if xml doc contains the namesapcecontext

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon

I am quite new to XML and Saxon API's, Here I am using Saxon 10.3 HE jar to extract the data from the XML file. Here I want to extract the country attribute from the active country_information node where I am using the date functions.
Sample input XML :

```
<person xmlns="urn:my.poctest.com">
                  <country_information>
                     <country>FRA</country>
                     <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                     <start_date>2009-12-01</start_date>
                  </country_information>
                  <country_information>
                     <country>FRA</country>
                     <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                     <start_date>2009-12-01</start_date>
                  </country_information>             
               </person>
```

Code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;

public class SaxonPoc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException,
            XPathExpressionException, XPathFactoryConfigurationException {
        String xml = " <person xmlns=\"urn:my.poctest.com\">\r\n"
                + "       <country_information>\r\n"
                + "          <country>FRA</country>\r\n"
                + "          <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>\r\n"
                + "          <start_date>2020-02-24</start_date>\r\n"
                + "       </country_information>\r\n" 
                + "       <country_information>\r\n"
                + "          <country>USA</country>\r\n"
                + "          <end_date>2020-02-23</end_date>\r\n"
                + "          <start_date>2009-12-01</start_date>\r\n"
                + "       </country_information>             \r\n" 
                + "       </person>";
        Document doc = SaxonPoc.getDocument(xml, false);
        NodeList matches = (NodeList) SaxonTest.getXpathExpression("//person", null).evaluate(doc,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
        if (matches != null) {
            Element node = (Element) matches.item(0);
            XPath xPath1 = SaxonPoc.getXpath(null);
            String xPathStatement = "/person/country_information[xs:date(start_date) le current-date() and  xs:date(end_date) ge current-date()]/country";
            NodeList childNodes = (NodeList) xPath1.evaluate(xPathStatement, node, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            if (childNodes.getLength() > 0) {
                String nodeName = childNodes.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeName();
                System.out.println("Node :" + nodeName);
                String value = childNodes.item(0).getTextContent();
                System.out.println("Country Name :" + value);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Finished");

    }

    public static Document getDocument(String xml, boolean isNamespaceAware)
            throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(isNamespaceAware);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        return builder.parse(is);
    }

    public static XPath getXpath(Map<String, String> namespaceMappings) throws XPathFactoryConfigurationException {
        XPathFactory xpathFactory = new XPathFactoryImpl();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        NamespaceContext nsc = new NamespaceContext() {

            @Override
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                return (null != namespaceMappings) ? namespaceMappings.get(prefix) : null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                return null;
            }

        };
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(nsc);

        return xpath;
    }

    public static XPathExpression getXpathExpression(String xpathExpr, Map<String, String> namespaceMappings)
            throws XPathExpressionException, XPathFactoryConfigurationException {
        XPath xpath = getXpath(namespaceMappings);
        return xpath.compile(xpathExpr);
    }

}
```

I am facing a null pointer as it is not able to find the root node **person** an XML doc. If I remove the **xmlns="urn:my.poctest.com"**  then it is able to get the root path but in a later stage, it is failing with **javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Namespace prefix 'xs' has not been declared**. If I remove the namespace from XML doc and NamespaceContext implementation from code then it is working fine. But here actually I don't want to remove both things.

Can someone point out me here, what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: see if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801754/regarding-xpath-parsing-of-xml-with-default-namespace-using-saxon

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442213/using-xpath-with-namespace-from-a-java-class

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835232/why-do-only-certain-xpath-expressions-find-nodes-when-xml-has-a-namespace-prefix

Comment: Would it be easier for you to use Saxon's proprietary `s9api` API and switch to XQuery https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQFp6 where you can declare any namespaces you want to use with e.g. `declare namespace` and where the schema namespace is predefined? That way you would have way less code to write in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to know that recent versions of Saxon include the option to do

```
((net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator)XPath).getStaticContext()
    .setUnprefixedElementMatchingPolicy(
       UnprefixedElementMatchingPolicy.ANY_NAMESPACE))
```

which causes an unprefixed element name in your XPath expression to match on local name alone, regardless of the namespace.

This was mainly introduced for HTML, where there is complete confusion as to whether elements in an HTML DOM are in a namespace or not; but it's useful more generally where you really don't care about the namespaces and just wish they weren't there to make your life a misery.